# Possible to open the newer, slicker AVD Manager window from the command line?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I know of two ways to open the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager window: to open it via Android Studio or by running the `android avd` command in Terminal.

I'm seeing however that the AVD Manager window which opens via Android Studio is considerably slicker and better than the window that opens with the `android avd` command.

**Is there any way to open the slicker and better AVD Manager window by means of the command line... or outside of Android Studio?** (I notice also in Android Studio that I have to open a project to be able to open the AVD Manager window which is a tad bit annoying.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that it's possible because the new AVD manager built with Swing framework and depends on Intellij IDEA platform.

> [Android Studio sources.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/03fd7a2ea00cb9a35ac4bdef2937af362a416c8c/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure you device in Android Studio via AVD Manager.
2. Get a list of working devices with `emulator -list-avds`
3. Start the desired device with `emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23`

Recently there is an bug in Android SDK which let you result in a QT-Lib-Missing-Bug. See [Cannot launch AVD in emulator:QT library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554337/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulatorqt-library-not-found)

Just use the emulator out of his directory (`~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/`) solves the problem for me.