# Android emulator does not run, few errors returned

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I have a HAXM enabled Pixel emulator that when I press run emulator in the AVD manager does nothing and returns no errors. Trying to run the avd manually with the commands yields:

```
C:\Users\Skyler\Desktop\AP>C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_API_25
[7604]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
```

So far I just haven't been able to get any other errors, the emulator seems unresponsive, and the "Stop" button is greyed out. I've tried running Android Studio as an admin to no avail either.

Here is HAXM status:

```
C:\Users\Skyler>sc query intelhaxm
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

EDIT: This error has disappeared, however now Windows 10 flags me with

```
This app cannot run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot launch AVD in emulator:QT library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554337/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulatorqt-library-not-found)

Comment: updated with new error message that is appearing

Comment: previous message disappeared on its own