# Why is Android Studio not finding the x86 emulator when running a flutter app?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

### **Software**

```
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
Android Studio 3.1.2
Flutter 0.3.2 • channel beta
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b
Flutter doctor (no problems found)
```

### **Problem**

I am using Android Studio IDE to develop flutter apps, but I can't get any of the Android virtual device emulators to launch from the IDE. Whenever an **Android virtual device** is selected, such as the ***Pixel P***, an error message appears saying **"PANIC: the emulator program for the x86 CPU is missing"**. However, the emulator does work when it is launched from the command line:

```
$ cd /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
$ emulator -avd Pixel_API_P
```

The problem seems to be specific to **flutter projects**, given that the same virtual devices are being launched normally with **Android projects**.

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266370/6156989

Comment: The emulator is installed, that's not the problem.

Comment: What does `flutter doctor` print?

Comment: It reported I was only missing the Dart & flutter pluguins for intelliJ. However, I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the virtual device's `x86` image to `x86_64` and the problem was solved. Still don't undertand the underlying cause, but it worked:

`ADV Manager > edit device > (name_of_device) Change... > x86 images > download & select x86_64 image`

[image]

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that we've been using the 32bit version (x86) rather than the 64bit one (x86_64).. therefore it's been having to emulate everything and therefore really slow..

Answer (score 0):

Check if your GPU rendering is activated in your BIOS settings.
Generally the BIOS keeps the GPU rendering off. You can change it, then clean your Android Studio, then reload your ADB.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The emulators launch with no problems with Android projects. The problem is specific to Android flutter apps.